# How to refresh a progress bar in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have tried to create this progress bar:

```
public class ProgressBar extends JFrame{

private JButton fine = new JButton("Chiudi");
final JProgressBar jp;
JPanel body;
JLabel banner1;
JLabel banner2;
JPanel testo;
JTextArea areatesto;
JPanel provapannello;
JTextArea provatesto;
JPanel pannellofine;

public ProgressBar() {
     super("loading");

    setSize(440, 400);
    setResizable(true);
    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    body = new JPanel();
    body.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("prova1.png");
    banner1 = new JLabel();
    banner2 = new JLabel();
    banner1.setIcon(image1);
    JTextArea prova = new JTextArea("bar", 2, 40);
    prova.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    prova.setLineWrap(true);
    body.add(banner1);
    body.add(prova);
    body.add(banner2);
    banner.setBounds(30, 80, 120, 120);
    testo = new JPanel();
    areatesto = new JTextArea("Attendi Per Favore, Sto Preparando Il Tuo PDF", 2, 33);
    areatesto.setLineWrap(true);
    testo.add(areatesto);
   ImagePanel progress_background = new ImagePanel("p.jpg"); 

    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", new Color(29, 29, 29));
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", new Color(16, 95, 173));
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", new Color(214, 214, 214));
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", new Color(29, 29, 29));

    jp = new JProgressBar();
    jp.setUI(new BasicProgressBarUI());

    jp.setBounds(0, 205, 434, 25);
    jp.setMinimum(0);
    jp.setMaximum(100);
    jp.setStringPainted(true);
    jp.setBorder(null);
    progress_background.add(jp);
    provapannello = new JPanel();
    provatesto = new JTextArea("prova", 2, 70);


    provatesto.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    provapannello.setBounds(0, 226, 500, 100);
    provapannello.add(provatesto);

    content.add(provapannello);
    content.add(progress_background);

    pannellofine = new JPanel();

    pannellofine.add(fine);
    pannellofine.setBounds(340, 330, 100, 100);
    pannellofine.setVisible(false);

    content.add(pannellofine);
    content.add(testo);

    content.add(body);
    Thread runner;
    jp.setValue(0);
    setVisible(true);
    public void setValue(final int j) {

    Runnable target = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jp.setValue(j);
        }
    };

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(target);

}
    public static void main(String Args[]) {
    ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar();


    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        System.out.println("work");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }

        p.setValue(i++);
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the value of the ProgressBar with the method "setValue" but the bar does not increase, "while" cycles to infinity, but I see no change. what's wrong?

Comment: but I see no change. what's wrong? - post an compilable code in  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) form

Comment: What do you see on progress bar? Empty? Or some animation happening?

Comment: The window opens but the bar doesn't appear

Comment: See the SwingWorker class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html.  It even uses update of a ProgressBar as the documentation example.

Comment: @user2784212 If you want help, you should provide a sample code reproducing the error, not some pieces of code that don’t even compile. On my machine this code works without problems after cleaning up the mess. So maybe the only thing you have to do is to cleanup your original source code as well.

Comment: You aren't running the GUI on the Swing worker thread. You are running it on the same thread you are sleeping on.

Comment: @Obicere: the `main` method runs in the “main” thread, the `Swing` UI will run in the event dispatch thread which is created automatically when the first `AWT` window is opened. And the `setValue` invoked from the “main” thread method uses `invokeLater`. So there’s nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've stripped out most of the unnecessary code (and fixed your compilation errors), and your example works (I've changed the delay and increment, because again, for reproduction purposes you shouldn't waste people's time)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ProgressBar extends JFrame {

    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressBar() {
        super("loading");
        setSize(200, 100);
        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setMinimum(0);
        progressBar.setMaximum(100);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setBorder(null);
        content.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void updateProgress(final int newValue) {
        progressBar.setValue(newValue);
    }

    public void setValue(final int j) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateProgress(j);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(final String Args[]) {
        ProgressBar myProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= 100) {
            System.out.println("" + i + "%");
            myProgressBar.setValue(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                break;
            }
            i = i + 5;
        }
    }
}
```

You should really have invested the time in creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Also on a side note, you should follow [this advice](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) when handling `InterruptedExcetion`s

Comment: Now everything is clearer. I did not know SSCCE, I promise that I have learned the lesson and I will be to be more orderly. I apologize for the mess and I thank you for the help